# How can I avoid rebuilding 15GB-8hr long PCL library every time I move to a new identical HW?

Tags: cmake, point-cloud-library, nvidia-jetson, cmake-format

I am using Jetson TX2 boards for my work with PCL and GPU. Since, GPU sub-systems are not available on any apt-repos, I am told to build them from source every time I move to a new system.

Since all HW is identical,how can I just copy the same PCL library built initially on other systems to new system and start using directly?
I kept getting the CMAKE error:

```
This directory is not where CMakeCache file was generated.
```

What is the way around this?

Comment: The CMake cache file contains all of the paths to your source and binary (generated) files that were configured on the previous machine. An error like this indicates that your new machine is actually **not** identical or you've placed the CMake build directory in a **different** location than its previous location on the old machine.

Comment: This could also indicate you ran different CMake commands than on the old machine... In general, I'm confused how you got this error. Can you please provide the **specific steps** you took on the new machine to get this error. If you want to avoid re-building, why are you running CMake and re-building on the new machine?

Comment: I mean identical Hardware. Sorry for the ambiguity

The locations,directories are identical.
The only difference is the username in full directories address:
`1. home/alpha/a/b/c`
`2. home/bravo/a/b/c`

I simply execute **sudo make install** in the copied build folder on new machine when I get the error.
I was hoping to change this alpha to bravo in few key config files to make it work.
Any hints?

Comment: Because the directories are different, CMake (and therefore `make`) will likely need to be re-run. You can try editing the CMakeCache.txt file. I would first update the `CMAKE_CACHEFILE_DIR`, but you probably have to update all instances of the `home/alpha` path in that file to get things working with CMake. At that point, however, CMake will likely need to re-generate all the Makefiles, and you're essentially starting from scratch. It may be easier to create a user account `alpha` on the new machine, and attempt the install from that directory.

Comment: @squareskittles I tried updating all instances. Also tried with new user as you suggested. still it started building again from 0%.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question but you can try using a Docker container with NVIDIA support. You can just transfer the built image across different hardware.